# Updating model data to match list

Tags: python, django

**Backround:** I am pulling data from an API and creating a list like the one below. Now this data set will be 50 entries each time, and changing just about every time I'm saving data into my model. So below i created a condensed version of what is going on in my Django project.  Also using djangos ORM the model data is also being put into a outside postgres db

I insert my data into my model by using a list like so:

```
   list = [(1, "open", "hello"), (2, "closed", "hey"), (3, "in progress", "never"), (4, "open", "free")]
```

and then saving these values into model 'Bug' like this

```
    for item in list:
        b = Bug(key=item[0],
                status=item[1],
                description=item[2])
        b.save()
```

Now say the list changes to this

```
list = [(3, "closed", "never"), (4, "closed", "free"), (5, "open", "never"), (6, "open", "great")]
```

(note the entry with "3" as the `key` has changed from "in progress" to "closed" and the item with "4" as the `key` has also changed to "close". This also adds entries with a `key` of "5" and "6")

With the existing saved model data from the first list, how can i update the saved model data to reflect the changes of the 2nd list? as well as add entries.

EDIT: so it seems that this code is already doing what I had intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
for item in list:
    b = Bug.objects.update_or_create(
            key=item[0],
            defaults={'status': item[1], 'description': item[2]})
    )
```

(You don't need to call `save` after this.)

**Edit**

If `key` is already the primary key, then you don't need to do anything - the original code will work fine. Django will update the original item if it exists, otherwise insert it: see [How Django knows to UPDATE vs INSERT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert).

Comment: would i need an import to be able to use `update_or_create()`?  I am getting an error like this `type object 'Bug' has no attribute 'update_or_create'`

Comment: Apologies, that should have been `Bug.objects.update_or_created`, updated.

Comment: I am now getting an error saying `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bug_pkey"` sorry if i didnt mention this but key is a primary key. It doesn't seem to let the things that are the same as the model go through

Comment: If `key` is the primary key, then you *literally* don't need to do anything at all. Your original code would work fine.

Comment: Wow, sorry i was misreading my data set... this is why i need to do unit testing... edit your answer to reflect this and ill mark it as resovled